# how can I access a variable parameter at spider class from pipelines.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, pipeline

I have 3 number of spider files and classes. And I want to save item informations at csv file which has different filename defendant the variable parameter of searching condition. For that, I need to access the spider class parameter.

So, my questions are three.

1. How can I access the spider class's parameter?
2. What is the best way to make each csv files? The trigger condition is that will call request at parse function for new searching result.
3. `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` it's not working in `pipelines.py`
   How can I print that information?

Bellow is my log code style

```
logger.log(logging.INFO,'\n======= %s ========\n', filename)
```

I had been searching the ways in google so many times. But I couldn't find the solution.

I did try to use from_crawler function, but I couldn't find the adapt case

```
Scrapy 1.6.0
python 3.7.3
os window 7 / 32bit
```

Code:

```py
class CensusGetitemSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'census_getitem'
    startmonth=1
    filename = None

def parse(self, response):
    for x in data:
       self.filename = str(startmonth+1)
       .
       .  
       .
       yield item

    yield scrapy.Request(link, callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Please, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask are also worth reading.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can access spider class and instance attributes from pipeline.py using the `spider` parameter passed in most of pipeline methods.

For example, :

```
open_spider(self, spider):
    self.filename = spider.name
```

You can see more about item pipelines here https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

2. You can save it directly from the command line, just define a filename:

`scrapy crawl yourspider -o output.csv`

But if you really need it to be set from the spider, you can use a custom setting per spider, for example:

```
 class YourSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yourspider'
    start_urls = 'www.yoursite.com'
    custom_settings = {
        'FEED_URI':'output.csv',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
    }
```

3. Use `spider.logger.info('Your message')`

Comment: thank you so much to reply my question.
i'll try to it and share the result this stack.

at first time I used command style.
but it wasn't created following the sequence of column.
So I tried to find the way, and I found that someone answered at the question about pipeline.
If I can handle column sequence, I hope to use command output option.
do you know about this?